# React Native List View handle Null

Tags: react-native

I am using a API that will return 10 objects no matter what, even if there are only 2 results. So the return values look something like this:

`[[object], [object], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null]]`

This causes problems with list view because it is expecting values.

Currently I am handling it like this:

```
renderRow(rowData) {
  if (rowData === null) { return <View></View>; };

  return (
    <SearchListItem
      title={ rowData.strProductName }
      price={ rowData.dblProductPrice }
      salePrice={ rowData.dblProductSalePrice }
      imageUrl={ rowData.strLargeImage }
      handleShare={ this._handleShare.bind(this) }
    />
  );
}
```

It seems to me that it is kind of hacky to just return a empty view.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Are you rendering each `SearchListItem` inside of a `for` loop? It'd be easy enough to check for `null` there and `continue` through the loop if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pre-process the model data and skip needing to switch between views:

```
var processed = _.map(rowData, (r) => {
    if (r === null)
        return { // contents of 'empty' model };
    else
        return r;
});
```

But do you want empty rows in your view? If not then you should use _.filter. If so, then the way you're doing it now, IMO, is the appropriate way to do so.